# Initializing mongo replica set only once

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am attempting to automatically deploy identical docker containers to multiple servers. The deployment consists of a python script and a mongodb database that should be connected in a replica set to the other mongodb instances.

I have found most of the setup for a replica set clear and well documented. However, while following [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#initiate-the-replica-set) tutorial I came across the following:

> Run `rs.initiate()` on *just one and only one* mongod instance for the replica set.

Suppose that the python script has access to an exhaustive list of the servers where the containers are to be deployed (but may not yet be running) **(i)** How can I ensure `rs.initiate()` is run only once for the entire replica set without manual intervention? **(ii)** What is the consequences of running `rs.initiate()` multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

A replica set has internal state information that is shared between all nodes. If you concurrently run `rs.initiate` on every single node, for example, each node will try to initiate *its own* replica set, and a node will refuse to join other nodes' replica sets because they are different replica sets.

Your provisioning logic needs to pick one node to run `rs.initiate` on.

You can do that by sorting the host names alphabetically for example and using the first host for initiating.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status beforehand:

```
if (rs.status().codeName == "NotYetInitialized") rs.initiate()
```

If you run `rs.initiate()` more than once, then you get an error:

```
{
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1612356173, 1),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "already initialized",
    "code" : 23,
    "codeName" : "AlreadyInitialized",
}
```